Add Bearing (WITH N,S,E,W) AND DISTANCE (M) To another coordinates (LAT, LON)
Good morning.
I would like to know how do I add kilometers to a map point (latitude / longitude).
For example: The city Jaraguá do Sul is in latitude -26.462049, longitude -49.059448. I want to add 100 kilometers up, down, and on the sides. I want to do a square and get the new points.
How do I do that?
I tried it:
<?php
$distance = 100;
$earthRadius = 6371;
$lat1 = -26.4853239150483;
$lon1 = -49.075927734375;
$bearing = 0; // PLEASE SHOW HOW TO ADD N,S,E & W

$lat2 = asin(sin($lat1) * cos($distance / $earthRadius) + cos($lat1) * sin($distance / $earthRadius) * cos($bearing));
$lon2 = $lon1 + atan2(sin($bearing) * sin($distance / $earthRadius) * cos($lat1), cos($distance / $earthRadius) - sin($lat1) * sin($lat2));

echo 'LAT: ' . $lat2 . '<br >';
echo 'LNG: ' . $lon2;
?>

it's returning wrong cordinates. Thank you!
Thank you very much.

Show us what the math is supposed to look like, what the correct answer is supposed to be,  and we can tell you if you implemented it correctly.

BngAngleDD = degree+min/60+sec/3600 (how to add the north, south, east or west. thanks

sample: S 68deg, 30mins E, Distance 3489.12

POINT 1: 14.603106, 121.448250 and then add this, S 68°, 30'mins E, Distance 3489.12

Sammitch is asking you to [edit] your question, not add question details as comments.

Do you assume spherical Earth? Is it to learn PHP, to learn maths or a real programming question (in later case: you should use appropriate libraries which can handle better imprecision of floats), if it maths, probably an other StackExchange (see links on top right icon) may be appropriate, if it is to learn PHP we should know, to answer in a better way (less tricks)
